# jQuery + How can I select only the first instance of each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

take the following html for example:

```
<h1>Level 1 Header</h1>
<h1>My Second Level 1 Header</h1>
<h1>And a third for kicks</h1>

<h2>Level 2 Header</h2>
<h2>2nd Level 2 Header</h2>

<p>Here is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Here is a paragraph number 2.</p>
<p>And paragraph number 3.</p>

<ul>
<li>list item 1<li>
<li>list item 2<li>
<li>list item 3<li>
<li>list item 4<li>
</ul>
```

How can I select only the first instance of each element?

I'm looking to hide all, in exception to "first" of each element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
 $('h1:first,h2:first,p:first,li:first')
```

To select the first element of each set into a jQuery set.

Comment: great, thanks. I was hoping there was almost a function I could write saying: 

1 - which / how many elements do we have in this container? 
2 - now that we know there are x number of elements, filter every first instance from selection. 

The problem I see with this answer, I could get long as an expression, I thought maybe there was a way for a script to check what was in document, as opposed to me specifying each one.

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

For best performance, avoid non-standard selectors, as they will force the Sizzle selector engine into the slower non-querySelectorAll code branch. Examples of non-standard selectors can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ (look for any selector that starts with ":")

With that in mind, you can apply the strategy to your use cases as follows:

```
$("h1").hide().eq(0).show();

$("h2").hide().eq(0).show();

$("p").hide().eq(0).show();

$("ul li").hide().eq(0).show();
```

For bonus performance improvements, replace hide()/show() with addClass()/removeClass() that adds and removes a class that defines `display` state changes.

For even more performance improvements, use :first-child whenever/wherever possible: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/w4Wz4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this implicitly, but it's pretty easy to select the first element explicitly:

```
$("h1:first").show();
```

To hide all but the first:

```
$("h1:gt(0)").hide();
```

And, piggybacking off of Tejs:

```
 $("h1:gt(0),h2:gt(0),p:gt(0),li:gt(0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the li case:

```
// hide all li and then show the first one
$('ul li').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
```

The other ones:

```
$('h1:first');

$('h2:first');

$('p:first');
```